# How to convert xml file into matrix in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab

I have 2600 xml files with data, I wonder if there's a easy way to convert them into tables in excel, or matrix in Matlab. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to answer without knowing more about the XML schema.

There's no "easy way" beyond parsing the XML and mapping the tree you get into tables of some kind.  You have to figure out what that mapping will be.  The parsing and setting values is the easy bit; the mapping is known only to you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`xmlread()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/xmlread.html), and see if that's any use to you.